# Predicate as lambda expression but depends on "external" parameters

Tags: java, lambda

I'm trying to make a `Predicate` in order to know that I'm
done with some records, but I need an external list of records that may be updated with time; also I need to keep track of the ones I already processed.

This is how the code looks like:

```
// This one is at class level and gets updated in different places
Set<String> recipients ...

private void method(Iterable<CustomType> records) {
  final Set<String> doneWith = new HashSet<>();

  try {
    someService.doThis(records, record -> { // records is a list of CustomType
      boolean notify = Stream.of(doneWith, recipients)
        .noneMatch(s -> s.contains(record.getField()));

      if (notify) {
        doneWith.add(record.getField());
      }
      return notify;
    });
    recipients.addAll(doneWith);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: Do something here
  }
}
```

...now I want to "externalize" into a `Predicate` the second parameter `someService.doThis(records, <this_one>`. Any clues?

This is the type of call:

```
public void doThis(Iterable<CustomType> records, Predicate<CustomType> notify) {
  records.forEach(r -> {
    // Do some stuff here
    if (notify.test(r)) {
      // Do some more stuff here
    }
  });
}
```

**NOTE:** The main reason want to be able to reuse the predicate it's because I may need it somewhere else, but as of now, it's also used in the test cases.

Comment: Er, what part of this is a `Predicate`?  And predicates really shouldn't modify external state, as you're doing in `doneWith`.  But really all you need to do is factor out a method that returns a `Predicate`, and return this lambda from it.

Comment: So you mean that making use of `doneWith` shouldn't be done in a `Predicate`?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your function is really just:

```
record -> !recipients.contains(record.getField()) 
          && doneWith.add(record.getField())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [BiPredicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiPredicate.html) as a parameter.

```
public void doThis(Iterable<CustomType> records, BiPredicate<CustomType, Iterable<CustomType> > shouldNotify) {
  final Set<String> doneWith = new HashSet<>();
  records.forEach(r -> {
    if (shouldNotify.test(r, doneWith)) {
      // Do something here
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to externalize your predicate, then you just need to make a new Predicate:

New Predicate:

```
@Builder
public class MyPredicate implements Predicate<CustomType> {
    private Set<String> doneWith;
    private Set<String> recipients;

    @Override
    public boolean test(CustomType record) {
        boolean notify = Stream.of(doneWith, recipients)
                .noneMatch(s -> s.contains(record.getField()));

        if (notify) {
            doneWith.add(record.getField());
        }
        return notify;
    }
}
```

New call:

```
private void methodName(Iterable<CustomType> records) {
    someService.doThis(records, MyPredicate.builder().doneWith(doneWith).recipients(recipients).build());
    recipients.addAll(doneWith);
}
```

Continuing the resolution of your issue I though this might be helpfull. Your predicate should basically only do tests. You are doing a change action within your predicate. If you move that out and make some changes you may have to change the structure of your code a bit:

New Predicate:

```
@Builder
public class MyPredicate implements Predicate<CustomType> {
    private Set<String> listToFind;

    @Override
    public boolean test(CustomType record) {
        return listToFind.parallelStream()
                .noneMatch(s -> s.contains(record.getField()));
    }

}
```

Your new call:

```
private void methodName(Iterable<CustomType> records) {
    someService.doThis(records,
            MyPredicate.builder().listToFind(recipients).build()
                    .and(MyPredicate.builder().listToFind(doneWith).build())
    );
    recipients.addAll(doneWith);
}
```

And finally your new service:

```
// TODO: Please consider using injection for your doneWith Set
final Set<String> doneWith = new HashSet<>();

public void doThis(Iterable<CustomType> records, Predicate<CustomType> shouldNotify) {
    records.forEach(r -> {
        if (shouldNotify.test(r)) {
// TODO: You continue here...
            doneWith.add(r.getField());
        }
    });
}
```

So, you now have a **predicate** that is actually an **AND** condition of both predicates. This way you know that only when all sets are missing your `customType` then you can add an element to your **doneWith** set. Your service will need to share this set and the best way to do that is with **Context Dependency Injection**. If you do this, you don't need to change your code that much and you will have a generic  Predicate which you can use generically and externally. The *BiPredicate* idea would work if you had at least two input variables which is not the case.